# Transer from table to notepad with separator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Goal:
Retrieve data in a notepad with ';' as a separator between column.
The data in the notepad should be:

```
2001-11-11 00:00:000;1
2001-11-11 00:00:000;2
2001-11-11 00:00:000;0
```

Problem:
How should I transfer data from table into notepad with this data

```
(datetime)               (int)
date                  Number
--------------------------------
2001-11-11 00:00:000       1
2001-11-11 00:00:000       2
2001-11-11 00:00:000       0
2001-11-11 00:00:000       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into tools-options Open the Query Results Tree, SQL Server, Results to Text. In there you will see output format and you should be able to choose custom delimiter which you can then set to a semi colon.

If you now change your output to the text (ctrl+T) or results to file (ctrl + shift + F) you should get the output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is MySQL for example, you just dump the database using:

```
mysqldump --fields-terminated-by=str databasename
```

where str is ";".

Answer (score 0):

select "results to file" on the menu and run:

```
select CAST(date as varchar(20))+';'+CAST(number as varchar(20))
from yourTable
```